# How to add Captions to YouTube videos using " Youtube Iframe API "

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I want to add captions to Youtube videos using "Youtube Iframe API".Youtube player object is created with iframe API,listed two videos for the player.

Following is my sample code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Video Player</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function Player(options) {  
        var defaults = {
            height: '250',
            width: '500',
            events: { 'onReady': null},
             cc_load_policy :1,
            playerVars: {
              modestbranding: 0,
              controls: 0, //remove controls
              showinfo: 0,
              version:2,
              enablejsapi : 1,
              iv_load_policy: 3,
              cc_load_policy :1
             }
          };

          var combinedOptions = $.extend(defaults, options);

          return {
            player: null,

            pause: function () {      
            this.player.pauseVideo();    
            },

            seek: function () {       
              //this.player.seekTo();          
            },

            destroy: function () {      
            this.player.destroy();    
            },

            changeVideo: function () {      
            this.player.stopVideo();    
            },

            onPlayerReady: function( a, b, c, d ) {
                myPlayer.player.playVideo();
                myPlayer.player.cuePlaylist({playlist:['u1zgFlCw8Aw','M7lc1UVf-VE'], startSeconds:0 });
            },

            onStateChange:function( a, b, c, d ){
            //myPlayer.player.seekTo(50);
            },

            init: function() {
            me = this;
            me.player = new YT.Player(combinedOptions.id, {
            height: combinedOptions.height,
            width: combinedOptions.width,
            events: {
                'onReady': this.onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': this.onStateChange
            }
            });
            }
        }
    };

    var myPlayer;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        myPlayer = new Player({  
            id: 'divId',
            autoPlay: true,
            videoId: 'NeGe7lVrXb0',
        });
        myPlayer.init();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);    
    });


    function playPause()
    { 
        if (myPlayer.player.getPlayerState() == 1) 
          myPlayer.player.pauseVideo(); 
        else 
          myPlayer.player.playVideo(); 
    } 
    function addTime()
    { 
        var playerObj = myPlayer.player;
        var currentTime = playerObj.getCurrentTime();
        playerObj.seekTo(currentTime+10);
    } 

    function removeTime()
    { 
        var playerObj = myPlayer.player;
        var currentTime = playerObj.getCurrentTime();
        playerObj.seekTo(currentTime-10);
    } 
    function makeBig()
    { 
        me.player.a.width=600; 
        me.player.a.height=350; 
    } 

    function makeSmall()
    { 
        me.player.a.width=350; 
        me.player.a.height=200; 
    } 

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align:center" >
<button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
<button onclick="removeTime()">10-</button>
<button onclick="addTime()">10+</button> 
<button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
<button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
<button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
<br> 
<div style="text-align:center" id="divId">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help ? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

not described in API documentation, but here

```
this.player.loadModule("captions");
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't load your own captions from the API.

Youtube iframe API only allows you to manage the general settings, like showing or not the CC button, and if showing CC by default or not.

Captions must be submitted by the uploader of the video. If have control over the video on youtube, you can edit the captions on youtube.

If you need to add your own captioning, you may considering using your own player and captionator.js

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for adding subtitle to a video (without existence on the original one): 
1-first disable access to "speed" control on the original video.
2-second add a markup layer by using DOM on top of your playing video iframe. 
3-third according to video time laps add subtitles for each scene.